# Linq Wpf Average query not populating datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid, average

I'm trying to get the average file size based on file extension and have it display in a datagrid. I have this method/query:

```
public List<FileTypeAverage> getAverageFileSizes(List<DirectoryItem> e)
{

    var result = e
        .Where(r => r.IsFile == true)
       .GroupBy(g => g.File.Extension, r => r.File.Length)
       .Select(g => new FileTypeAverage(g.Key, g.Average()));

    return result.ToList();
}
```

and i set the result to the viewSource.Source, but nothing is displayed in the datagrid. I'm thinking something is wrong with my query since I'm new to Linq, but I can't seem to figure out how it's supposed to be done. I know the list I'm passing in isn't empty since I display the list before passing it to the method and trying to display the averages.

Edit:
I use the method here:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource fileTypeAverageViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("fileTypeAverageViewSource")));
    fileTypeAverageViewSource.Source = sorter.getAverageFileSizes(List);
}
```

}

DirectoryItem class:

```
 public class DirectoryItem
    {
        public bool IsFile { get; }
        public DirectoryInfoPlus Dir { get; set; }
        public FileInfo File { get; }
        public FileSystemInfo Either { get { return IsFile ? (File as FileSystemInfo) : (Dir.Dir as FileSystemInfo); } }

        public DirectoryItem(DirectoryInfoPlus dir)
        {
            Dir = dir;
            IsFile = false;
        }

        public DirectoryItem(FileInfo file)
        {
            File = file;
            IsFile = true;
        }


    }
```

DirectoryInfoPlus is just a DirectoryInfo and combined size of all files in it stored in a long.

Comment: What do you in `result` once this method is done executing? Debug!!!

Comment: Does the method `getAverageFileSizes` called in secondary thread?

Comment: I use the method to set the view source. I'll edit it to show that.

Comment: Also post DirectoryItem class.

Comment: I added the DirectoryItem class.

Comment: Dir.Dir in your code returns FileSystemInfo. Can you post DirectoryInfoPlus  too.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code. The LINQ query is fine.

You have to just set the ItemsSource property like below :

```
Dgrid.ItemsSource = getAverageFileSizes(records);
```

CollectionViewSource is not needed.

But if it is what you want to use, then show how you have declared it, and trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I solved my problem. It was that my List was not being set properly before I queried it.
I had:

private void typesSizeButt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TypeSizeDisplay sizeDisplay = new TypeSizeDisplay();

```
    if(sizeDisplay.ShowDialog() == true){
       sizeDisplay.List = DirectoryItems;
    }
}
```

I changed it to:

private void typesSizeButt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TypeSizeDisplay sizeDisplay = new TypeSizeDisplay();
        sizeDisplay.List = DirectoryItems;
        sizeDisplay.ShowDialog();
    }